# Spring MongoDB template: Customize converters

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have customized my Spring MongoConfiguration since the persistent Enums did not match the Java enum names. The configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(host);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
        converterList.add(new MyEnumMongoConverter());

        return new MongoCustomConversions(converterList);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except for nested JSON objects. These objects are not being converted to their correponding POJO's. It seems that only the custom Converters are being used.

I want to **add** my custom converters to the standard provided ones **instead** of **replacing** them. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

your configuration is correct but you should register 2 customs converters one for POJO to Document and the other is from Document to POJO